# How to destroy a dependent if it is aliased?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependent-destroy

```rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord

end
```

```rb
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :winner, class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :loser, class_name: 'Team'
end
```

Thanks in advance.  Is it possible to write a dependence for destroy a belonged `Game` instance when a `Team` instance is destroyed? I didn't find anything on it, all things, I tried, like

```rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games, inverse_of: :winner, dependent: :destroy
...
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `foreign keys`

```rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :winner_games, foreign_key: :winner_id, class_name: 'Game', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :loser_games, foreign_key: :loser_id, class_name: 'Game', dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It doesn't work as is unfortunately: 
`uninitialized constant Team::WinnerGame`.  
Has something else to be added?

Comment: class_name: 'Game'